# Is there a kind of financial advisor for stock investors? How to find a good one?

Tags: stocks, investing, financial-advisor, rsu

I've been at a company for a few years and have some restricted stock units (RSUs) that have vested. I'm on E*Trade and know a little about stocks, but I'm no expert.

Is there a financial advisor of some kind, someone people usually speak with to get guidance and create a plan to reach investment goals etc., for something like this?

Would I find one through E*Trade, through another company, etc.? How do I find a *good* one? Or do people usually handle stocks by themselves?

Comment: They are called financial advisors or financial planners, or if you learn for yourself you can use an online broker yourself.

Comment: 10 bucks says anyone you speak to suggests you give them your money to handle for you if you give them that story lol. If you want to buy and sell on your own then do yourself a favor and do it with pretend money for at least 6 months. It will save you TONs in educational losses. Otherwise give your money to an advisor to a professional to handle for you.

Comment: If you have the time to invest, one suggestion is go through the CFA course material(it is targetted primarily towards creating portfolio  managers). It is in detail and all in one place. Easily dowloadable, or get it from your nearest library or loan it from a friend(or person you know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a retired stockbroker/Registered Investment Advisor. My initial discussions with prospects never had a fee. 
Restricted stock is unsaleable without specific permission from the issuing company, and typically involves time specifc periods when stock can be sold and/or amounts of stock that can be sold. Not for DIY. Financial planners may be able to assist you, if they are conversant in restricted stock, though that's not a common situation for most clients. Any stockbroker at a major firm (Merrill Lynch, UBS, Royal Bank of Canada, Morgan Stanley, JP Morgan, etc.) will be knowledgeable and advise you (w/o charge) how to trade the stock. Always talk to more than one firm, and don't be in a hurry. If you feel comfortable with the discussion, you can pursue a deeper relationship. In my professional experience, clients valued service, accessibility, knowledge. Price was way down on the list; many of my clients were not wealthy people- they just needed help navigating a very confusing (and necessary) part of their lives. Good luck.